# Me da fallo al cargar una imagen por Glide. The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas, estoy intentando añadir una imagen en la aplicacion a traves de Glide o piccasa y me da los dos el mismo fallo y no se el por que-

The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Creo que me falla porque no cojo bien el context

Es una clase que hereda de `Fragment`.

Poniendo `v.getContext()`, `getActivity()` o `this` en `with()`, da el mismo fallo siempre

```
public class Premios extends Fragment {

    public static final String URL = "http://frasesconindirectas.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Im%C3%A1genes-para-Celular-Divertidas-con-Movimiento.jpg";

    ImageView image;

    public Premios() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_premios, container);

        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        Glide.with(this).load(URL).into(image);

        return  v;
    }
```

A ver si alguien sabe el porque T-T

Comment: era eso, gracias =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es aquí :

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_premios, container);
```

cambia la linea a:

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_premios, container, false);
```

La definición del tercer parámetro es:

> Un valor booleano que indica si se debe anexar el diseño aumentado al
>   ViewGroup (el segundo parámetro) durante el agrandamiento. (En este
>   caso, es falso porque el sistema ya está insertando el diseño
>   aumentado al container; **al pasar true se crearía un grupo de vistas
>   redundante en el diseño final**).

Si no agregas el tercer parámetro, se define por default un valor true, el cual esta provocando que al volver a inflar el layout te requiera eliminar primero la "vista actual".

Información acerca de **[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)**